# Longest string with all unique substrings

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

All substrings of length 2 of the binary string $1011$ are unique, as well as all 2-substrings of $10011$. 5 seems to be the longest possible string with all unique 2-substring.

$000101100$ is a string where all 3-substring are unique

Given an alphabet A with $|A|=n$ and a substring-length m what is the longest string with all unique substrings of length $m$? (definitely $\le n^m+1$)

Is there an algorithm to get this longest string?

To me it looks somehow related to cyclic Grey codes!

Comment: A longer one with all unique 3-substrings: 0001011100

Comment: With unique 4-substrings: 0000100110101111000 (maximal length seems to be 19)

Comment: On 3 letters with unique 2-substrings: 0010211220 (maximal length seemingly 10)

Comment: These are deBruijn sequences, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Comment: @GerryMyerson Might be equivalent, if all of them are spliceable into cyclic words. In all the above examples this is the case ($m$ zeros to the left, $m-1$ zeros to the right), but I do not immediately see whether this is always the case

Comment: Here are the first few generating functions for the number of words with minimal length of unique substrings: $$2q,\\ 2q^2 + 2q,\\ 2q^3 + 6q^2,\\ 2q^4 + 6q^3 + 8q^2,\\ 2q^5 + 6q^4 + 20q^3 + 4q^2,\\ 2q^6 + 6q^5 + 20q^4 + 36q^3,\\ 2q^7 + 6q^6 + 20q^5 + 58q^4 + 42q^3,\\ 2q^8 + 6q^7 + 20q^6 + 58q^5 + 122q^4 + 48q^3,\\ 2q^9 + 6q^8 + 20q^7 + 58q^6 + 164q^5 + 222q^4 + 40q^3,\\ 2q^{10} + 6q^9 + 20q^8 + 58q^7 + 164q^6 + 380q^5 + 378q^4 + 16q^3,\\ 2q^{11} + 6q^{10} + 20q^9 + 58q^8 + 164q^7 + 430q^6 + 810q^5 + 558q^4,\\ 2q^{12} + 6q^{11} + 20q^{10} + 58q^9 + 164q^8 + 430q^7 + 1024q^6 + 1674q^5 + 718q^4$$

Comment: Seems that there is some stabilization going on.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Possibly some such sequences cannot be made into cyclic words, but this does not matter. The point is that De Bruijn sequences *exist* for arbitrary $n$ and $m$, and such a De Bruijn sequence, with its first $m-1$ letters repeated at the end, gives a string of length $n^m+m-1$ with all (contiguous) $m$-substrings unique. Since this is clearly also an upper bound, the answer to the question is exactly $n^m+m-1$. (The OP apparently miscounted with the $n^m+1$ bound.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes I agree. Seems like I switched to the enumeration question without noticing it myself. The number of De Bruijn sequences is known, I had in mind whether there are those of the kind OP is asking about which cannot be obtained from De Bruijn sequences in the way you describe.

Comment: The smallest number such that all substrings of this length are unique is now http://findstat.org/St000922.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A016031